# How does the amount of file transfer in EC2 constiture towards pricing in Amazon EC2?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, cygwin

I'm using amazon EC2 created Ubuntu server for transloading file to my Windows 7 localhost using Cygwin64 ssh & scp commands.

As I'am using EC2 t1.micro instances for file transfer from remote server to my localhost via ec2-ubuntu account, I was wondering, how does this large file transfers ended up in monthly bill.

Answer (score 1):

Not an absolute answer, but maybe some hints for you:

Check out [AWS calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) and play around with some values (data transfer in/out). Also have a look at the IOPS on your t1.micro, that can affact your monthly bill. A good estimate can prevent you from a higher bill than expected.